# How to publish IOS version of xamarin app via visual studio in windows?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I need to publish my android app that make it with visual studio enterprise 2017 and get IOS version of My App. 
How to do this?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to compile your Xamarin application on iOS, you must have a Mac machine and deploy your app through there. You are not able to deploy an iOS version of your application on Windows, unless you are tethering to a Mac device through LAN for example using Visual Studio 2017.

Chick [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/) out too, hope it helps!